# Strange color changes to a BufferedImage after saving it as a PNG file with ImageIO.write

Tags: java, image, colors, png

I've been trying to make a Java program that will allow some pixel colors to be changed to other colors in a `BufferedImage`, but the colors that are being drawn seem to be overlaid over the old ones. Here's what I mean:

[image: Combined image of input.png and output.png]

This is the code that's on the .java file at the moment:

```
static BufferedImage image = null;
static File file = null;
static int height;
static int width;
static int[][][] pixelStorage;
static int pixel;
static int getPixelDataOutput = 0;
static Random random = new Random();

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("test");

    try {
        file = new File("C:\\Users\\kkosy\\Dev\\Java\\Random\\Images - Color Changer\\Images\\input.png");
    }catch(Exception exception) {
        System.out.println(exception);
    }

    image = ImageIO.read(file);

    height = image.getHeight();
    width = image.getWidth();

    pixelStorage = new int[height][width][4];

    for(int h = 0; h < height - 1; h++) {
        for(int w = 0; w < width - 1; w++) {
            savePixelData(w, h);
            if(getPixelData(w,h,"r") == 0){
                System.out.println();
                printPixelData(w,h,"Before -- ");
                setPixelData(w,h,255,0,0,255);
                printPixelData(w,h,"After -- ");
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        file = new File("C:\\Users\\kkosy\\Dev\\Java\\Random\\Images - Color Changer\\Images\\output.png");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
    }catch(Exception exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }

}

private static void savePixelData(int x, int y) {
    pixel = image.getRGB(x,y);
    pixelStorage[y][x][0] = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
    pixelStorage[y][x][1] = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
    pixelStorage[y][x][2] = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
    pixelStorage[y][x][3] = pixel & 0xff;
    //printPixelData(x,y,"");

}

private static void setPixelData(int x, int y, int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {
    int setPixel = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue);
    image.setRGB(x, y, setPixel);
    image.setRGB(x, y, new Color(red,green,blue).getRGB());
}

private static void printPixelData(int x, int y, String arguments) {
    System.out.println(arguments + "" + pixelStorage[y][x][0] + " " + pixelStorage[y][x][1] + " " + pixelStorage[y][x][2] + " " + pixelStorage[y][x][3] + " ");
}

private static int getPixelData(int x, int y, String argb) {
    switch(argb) {
    case "a": {
        getPixelDataOutput = pixelStorage[y][x][0];
        break;
    }
    case "r": {
        getPixelDataOutput = pixelStorage[y][x][1];
        break;
    }
    case "g": {
        getPixelDataOutput = pixelStorage[y][x][2];
        break;
    }
    case "b": {
        getPixelDataOutput = pixelStorage[y][x][3];
        break;
    }
    }
    return getPixelDataOutput;
}
```

I have no idea why it outputs such an image. Perhaps it's the `setRGB()` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create a PNG file, but this line...

```
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
```

...is trying to write a JPEG.
According to the Unix `file` command, the output is indeed a JPEG...
also with a bad case of dark cyan pixels.

When I changed `"jpg"` to `"png"`, I got an `output.png` file that looked exactly the same as `input.png`.

I don't know what you *want* the output to look like
(and I'm using a
[different input file](https://encrypted.google.com/images/nav_logo229.png))
but this seems closer than the miscolored JPEG-in-PNG's-clothing.

---

Your log will be useless for debugging, because `printPixelData` always prints the values in `pixelStorage`.
Since `setPixelData` only changes the values in `image`, you will always print the "before" values twice, and never the "after" values.

As an aside, all those static variables make tracing the program's execution *much* harder than it has to be.
At least move what you can into methods
(like `height`, `width`, and `file`, which are never used outside of `main`),
and delete the ones you don't use at all
(like `getPixelDataOutput` and `random`).

---

Probably unrelated, but the `setPixelData` method sets a pixel, and then immediately resets it to some other value:

```
private static void setPixelData(
  int x, int y,
  int alpha, int red, int green, int blue
) {
    int setPixel = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | (blue);
    image.setRGB(x, y, setPixel);
    // Why overwrite the value you just set?
    image.setRGB(x, y, new Color(red,green,blue).getRGB());
}
```

This doesn't seem to change anything ---
(my test image looked the same with or without the first call to `setRGB` ---
but it's probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I had a second setRGB in the setPixelData method just so I could test some things, to see if the color was to get fixed, but thanks to your notice of the JPG and PNG error,

ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
I've managed to fix the mistake, thanks a lot!